# How do I use the Sitecore CLI with Sitecore Cloud to serialize content?

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli, xm-cloud

I've been watching all of videos about XM Cloud (https://developers.sitecore.com/learn/getting-started/xm-cloud-introduction) and I have a question about serialization? How is it working on XM Cloud?

There is a Andy Cohen's video (https://youtu.be/a23g2TRUvOI) that he's using sitecore cloud commands and I'm not finding this CLI.

Comment: Do you have the latest Sitecore CLI? Have you installed the XM Cloud plugin? Do you have an XM Cloud organization to connect to?

Comment: Not yet, @JasonSt-Cyr. I've been using the sitecore demo portal to study purpose. Thanks for your points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/xmcloud-preview/package/nuget/Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.XMCloud` reference:

```
dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.XMCloud
```

Then you should be able to use the command like this below:

```
dotnet sitecore cloud login
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. I forgot to mention, but I'm using JSS with NextJS and I'm not finding the sitecore.json to install this module, so I think I'll need to create the .Net part to enable serialization. Thank you very much for your help.